# android - best way to get a phone number with a name string such as "Bob"

Tags: java, android

Goal: take results from recognizer stating a name in contacts, then dial their #.

Is their an intent that will do this without a page of code??

I have no hair left , as I have spent too much time reading/etc... PLEASE help??

Update:
I have learned basically to query base contact records with URI in ContactsContract.Contracts.CONTENT_URI as STEP #1 within @override OnCreate.

Then in OnActivityResults you must query the phone number table as they are separate , but you will need the user ID to get the # is why you 1st do step #1.

or can i avoid step #1 and just URI query the phone table?

THEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No intent, but the easiest way to get to this data is to use ContactsContract:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html